# How to pass an array of objects from actionscript to javascript

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, actionscript

AS3:

```
ExternalInterface.addCallback('getParams', getParams);
function getParams()
        {
            var params:Array = new Array();
            for(i = 0; i < images.length; i++)
            {
                params.push(picWin.getChildAt(i));
            }

            return params;
        }
```

JS:

```
$('#button').click(function(){

        var res = document.getElementById("swfobject").getParams();
        alert(res);

    })
```

So after i get an error of some NPO object error, can't figure it out what it means, but if I pass an array itself its ok, if I pass an object itself it will be also ok, but when i pass an array of objects it gives me an error NPO, how to fix this?

Comment: also it happens when i try to pass an object with objects within

Comment: your return within AS is only within AS. In order to send something back to JS you need to use ExternalInterface.call();

Answer (score 2):

To pass from AS to JS you want to use

```
ExternalInterface.call("myJsFunction", myArray);
```

for this example, you need 2 JS functions: the first handles the click and sends a request to your swf. The second is called by the swf with your return value:

AS3:

```
ExternalInterface.addCallback('getParams', getParams); // listens for JS to getParams 
function getParams()
    {
        var params:Array = new Array();
        for(i = 0; i < images.length; i++)
        {
            params.push(picWin.getChildAt(i));
        }

        ExternalInterface.call("handleParams", params); // calls a js function and passes params 
    }
```

JS:

```
$('#button').click(handleClick)

function handleClick(event){
    document.getElementById("swfobject").getParams(); //sends request to swf
}

function handleParams(params){ // handles response from swf
     alert("You got an array with " + params.length + " elements back from flash.");
}
```